# Classify as pointwise, local at some $a\in I$, local on $I$, or global

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

Classify as pointwise, local at some $a\in I$, local on $I$, or global (assume the series converge in the relevant interval or neighborhood).

(a) $f(x)$ can be represented by a series $\sum a_nx^n$ in a neighborhood of $0$;

(b) $f(x)$ can be represented by a series $\sum a_nx^n$ in $(-1,1)$;

(c) $f(x)$ can be represented by $\sum_1^\infty x^n/n^2$ in $(-1,1)$;

(d) for each $x_0 \in (-1,1), f(x)$ can be represented by a series of the form $\sum a_n(x-x_0)^n$ convergent in some neighborhood of $x_0$.

I think (a) is local at some $a\in I$, (b) and (c)  pointwise, (d)  local on $I$. I don't see the difference between (b) and (c). So, am I right?

Comment: What does "pointwise, local ", etc.  mean here? For example, (a) means f is analytic (for our purposes, infinitely differentiable) in some neighborhood of zero, whereas (b) means the same *in the* neighborhood $\;(-1,1)\;$ ...

Comment: It's the type of property of $f(x)$. For example, a property that $f(x)$ is bounded by $K$ on $I$ is pointwise, since to verify it, we check that $\lvert f(a) \rvert \le K$ at each point $a \in I$. Another property that $f(x)$ is bounded on $I$ is global: no such pointwise check is possible, since we do not know in advance what the bound is.

Comment: Well, that was a weird explanation...In particular the @pointwise@ thigy, which is used in way another context. I shall check that book by Mattuck.

Comment: The question was on page-149.

Comment: Yes, I already read it. Thank you. And I read some of his explanations for names. He even points (pun intended) out that "punctual" would be a better name than "pointwise", which really confuses in this context. His other explanations aren't very clear and not very convincing, too.